# How to access fiber local data from side-effecting code in ZIO

Tags: scala, zio

I know that `FiberRef` is the fiber aware equivalent to Javas `ThreadLocal`. However, how can I store away fiber specific information for side effecting code? Basically, what I'm looking for is something similar to [monix.execution.misc.Local](https://monix.io/api/3.0/monix/execution/misc/Local.html) in order to do something in the direction of 
[Oleg Pyzhcov post on better logging with Monox](https://olegpy.com/better-logging-monix-1/).

Comment: What about using the Environment?