# How to get the ID of the currently executing ZIO fiber from side effecting code

Tags: scala, zio

I know that I can get hold of the ID of the currently executing fiber by calling

```scala
ZIO.descriptor.map(_.id)
```

However, what I want, is an impure function that I can call from side effecting code, lets define it like

```scala
def getCurrentFiberId(): Option[FiberId]
```

so that

```scala
for {
  fiberId <- ZIO.descriptor.map(_.id)
  maybeId <- UIO(getCurrentFiberId())
} yield maybeId.contains(fiberId)
```

yields true. Is it possible to define such a function, and if so, how? Note that this question is strongly related to [How to access fiber local data from side-effecting code in ZIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238805/how-to-access-fiber-local-data-from-side-effecting-code-in-zio).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. That information is contained in an instance of a class called `FiberContext` which is practically the core of the ZIO `Runtime` in charge of interpreting the Effects.

Also, such class is internal implementation and understandably package private.

Additionally there's not only one instance for it, but one for each time you `unsafeRun` an effect and one more each time a `fork` is interpreted.

As execution of an effect is not bound to a Thread, `ThreadLocal` is not used and so, no hope of somehow extracting that info the way you want.